# Removing an item from a div, and adding it to another div (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html page. When i hit the move button, i want to delete a specific item (item2) from first div and add it to second div. (Ultimately these items will be replaced with images.. but that is for later...)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
            #div1 {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 40px;
            background: lightGrey;
            }

            #div1 li{
                width: 150px;
                padding: 10px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                background: lightBlue;
                color: white;
            }

            #div2 {
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 40px;
            background: lightGrey;
            }

            #div2 li{
                width: 150px;
                padding: 10px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                background: lightBlue;
                color: white;
            }
    </style>
    <script>

        function move()
        {
            //??? What goes here ???
        }

        function show1()
        {
            alert($('#div1').html());
        }

        function show2()
        {               
            alert($('#div2').html());
        }
    </script>

<body>
        <div id="div1">

            <li id="item1">Item 1</li>
            <li id="item2">Item 2</li>
            <li id="item3">Item 3</li>
        </div>

        <div id="div2">

            <li id="item4">Item 4</li>
            <li id="item5">Item 5</li>
            <li id="item6">Item 6</li>
        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Move" onClick="move()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Show Div1 Elements" onClick="show1()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Show Div2 Elements" onClick="show2()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**What should i write in the move function to achieve this?**
When i click on Show Div1 or Show Div2 buttons, it should correctly show the elements. 
I will need to track these too i.e find which divs have what items.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, using the [appendTo method](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) :

```
function move() {
    $('#item2').appendTo('#div2')
}
```

Comment: Lucas i have posted a related drag n drop question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788504/drag-and-drop-an-item-from-one-div-to-another-with-correct-html-too-jquery-jav

Answer (score 0):

You can try

http://api.jquery.com/append/

and

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

You can also

use

http://api.jquery.com/children/

and

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score -1):

```
 // From which you will get content     
 var a=document.getElementById('youritem').innerHTML;

 // Get all content from container then append content and generate new content
 var c=document.getElementById('#div2').innerHTML;
 var b=a+c;

 // Then assign new content to Your div
 document.getElementById('#div2').innerHTML=b;

 // --------- or you can use

 function move() {
   $('#item').appendTo('#yourdiv')
 }
```